# Subtracting time in python where the result is always positive

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to compute differences in time as follows:

```
import datetime

time_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('18:00',"%H:%M")
time_2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('05:00',"%H:%M")

time_interval = time_2 - time_1
```

This results in:

```
datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=39600)
```

Now, when I add this to some date like:

```
low_date = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 18, 0)
low_date + time_interval
```

This results in:

```
datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 4, 0)
```

So, it is representing going backwards in time but I always want the difference to go forward i.e. `time_2` should be interpreted as being in the future of `time_1`. In this case, `time_2` is `5 AM` the next day.

If `time_2` was something like:

```
time_2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('21:00',"%H:%M")
```

It should be interpreted as `9 PM` on the same day.

**EDIT**

Solved it by adding something like:

```
if time_interval.days < 0:
    time_interval = datetime.timedelta(
         days=0,
         seconds=time_interval.seconds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both times you give are **in the same day**.

If you mean the second one to always be in the **future** (positive difference), you need to move it into the future, if it's not already. Check it for being "smaller", and if it's smaller, you have to add a day to it.

```py
time_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('18:00',"%H:%M")
time_2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('05:00',"%H:%M")

if time_2 < time_1:
    time_2 += datetime.timedelta(days=1)

time_interval = time_2 - time_1
# datetime.timedelta(seconds=39600)
# that's 6+5 = 11 hours = 39600 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract `time_2` from `time_1`, otherwise you will end with negative and nonsense values:

```
import datetime

time_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('18:00',"%H:%M")
time_2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('05:00',"%H:%M")

if time_1 <= time_2:
    time_1, time_2 = time_2, time_1
    
time_interval = time_1 - time_2
print(time_interval)
```

**Output:**

```
13:00:00
```

Comment: But this is unsatisfactory....the whole thing will fail if time_2 is say something like `21:00`

Comment: @luca In that case, OP should switch dates

Comment: @Luca - I am sorry, I don't understand how it will fail for `21:00` - the difference will be positive then, right?

Comment: @mortz He just has to switch dates, I added it to the question.

Comment: The above answer is wrong. The interval should be 11.00 not 13 as it is 5 AM the next day i.e. time_2 is in the future. I am trying to get this to work as `between_times`.

Comment: @luca You don't know the day of each date as the OP provided indefinite examples